# How to order and select query with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some conditions ORDER price ASC
```

The whole query is a bit more:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE some conditions ";
if (($_GET['Category']) =='X'){
switch( $_GET['price'] ){
    case '':
        $query_RS_Search .= ' some conditions ORDER BY price  ASC';
        break;
    case '0-500':
        $query_RS_Search .= ' some conditions ORDER BY price ASC';
        break;
    case '500-1000':
        etc
        break;  

}else{switch( $_GET['price'] ){
case '':
        $query_RS_Search .= ' some conditions ORDER BY price  ASC';
        break;
    case '0-500':
        $query_RS_Search .= ' some conditions ORDER BY price ASC';
        break;
    case '500-1000':
        etc
        break;  }}
```

what I would like to do is the same query but is the price is 0.00 this need to be the last instead of the first.

For example I have the following products:

```
product 1 price £15
product 2 price £25
product 3 price £12
product 4 price £0
```

I would like to order them as follows:

```
product 3 £12
product 1 £15
product 2 £25
product 4 £0
```

However the order I get is:

```
product 4 £0
product 3 £12
product 1 £15
product 2 £25
```

Any help welcome

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE some conditions ORDER BY price DESC

Comment: Can you also post one of the actual values that variable `$query_RS_Search` is set to?

Comment: what is some conditions?

Comment: one of the conditions is the price BETWEEN 0 AND 500

Comment: The problem that you are facing is most probably due to incorrect build up of `$query_RS_Search` variable. If you post an actual value this variable gets during your program execution, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos Thanks so much for your help I sorted it it was an ' I missed out somewhere. Thanks again so sticking with me to sort it swell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `ORDER BY Price = 0, Price ASC`

The `Price = 0` condition in the `ORDER BY` clause will return a value of `0` or `1` if the result is `false` or `true` respectively. And by default it will be sorted in *ascending* order.

Therefore, the prices which are equal to `0` will have a result of `1 (true)` base from the `Price = 0` condition, and will be placed on the last rows because `1 (true)` is greater than `0 (false)`.

See the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/24931)** sample

Even if the data type of `Price` is `DECIMAL`, equating it to `0` or `0.00` will sort on the order that you want.

Take a look at this another **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e9b1f/2)** sample.

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply, however the product with he price £0 is still on the top.

Comment: @Ria really? The query should work against mysql databases. Have you checked the sqlfiddle sample?

Comment: HI Thanks again for your reply, the only thing \I have different is that the price is 0.00 and I tried to change this as follows: ORDER BY Price = 0.00, Price ASC however that didn't work

Comment: @Ria I updated my answer. There must be something missing on your question that's why you are still getting the `0` prices on top.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I missed an ' when I changed the price thanks so much for your help

Comment: Good to know @Ria!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
ORDER BY price ASC
```

use:

```
ORDER BY IF(price = 0, 1, 0), price ASC
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38de3e/1)

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply, however the product with he price £0 is still on the top.

Comment: @Ria Then either price is not a number, or you have misused my query. Can you create a demo, like the one of my answer, that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. The only thing that is different could be the price is in the table as 0.00 would that make a difference as I did try and change it to IF(price = 0.00, 1, 0), price ASC. But that didn't work.

Comment: @Ria What is the exact type of field `price`?

Comment: it is a decimal(10,2)

Comment: @Ria Can you post the actual query you are using? (as-is)

Comment: I have updated the original question with a more expanded query. Hope that explains it a bit

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to order by price ascending except when price is 0 then it needs to be last.

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN price = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, price ASC
```

If your price contains the actual pound sign, first of all that isn't good database design, but second of all, you'll have to modify the query to:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN price = '£0'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, price ASC
```

This way the first priority ordering happens by a pseudo field that is only 1 when the price is 0 and will be ordered ascending, this means any price != 0 will be first before and price == 0. After that, we continue to order by price ascending. in your example, this would be:

```
product 3 £12
product 1 £15
product 2 £25
product 4 £0
```

Keep in mind, this will not work for any negative prices. If negative prices to also show up last, you'll have to modify the CASE statement to apply to `price <= 0` instead.

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply, however the product with he price £0 is still on the top.

Comment: @ria does the price literally say 0 or is it with the pound sign? I made an edit to address that case

Comment: it is without the pound sign the field is a decimal(10,2)

Comment: That should work then. Can you post your complete query and other interferences that might happen, as well as the exact data types of the involved fields?